# Mysql Database query with if condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name video

table video

```
id  name   upload_date

1   one     1408336348
2   two     1409884215
```

now i want to select all data also calculate if video uploaded between last 2 days then yes or no

result like

```
 id  name   upload_date   new

1   one     1408336348    no
2   two     1409884215    yes
```

I am using this query but not work

```
SELECT v.*,( if(from_unixtime(v.upload_date) < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) then 'no' else 'yes') 
 AS new FROM `video` as v
```

Query return error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') then 'no' else 'yes') 
AS new FROM `video` as v
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

Comment: What does your query return?

Comment: What means "not work?". Any errors or wrong result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using case

```
SELECT v.*
    ,case
        when (from_unixtime(v.upload_date) < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) then 'yes'
        else 'no')
     end AS new
FROM `video` as v
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not the correct syntax for an [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) in MySQL.  Try it like this:

```
SELECT v.*,
    IF(from_unixtime(v.upload_date) < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY, 'yes', 'no') AS new
FROM `video` as v
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a CASE statement:

```
SELECT v.*, 
    CASE WHEN from_unixtime(v.upload_date) < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY 
         THEN 'Yes' 
         ELSE 'No' 
    END AS new 
FROM `video`
```

This is the ansi-standard way to do it in SQL.